# Remove Unused (Empty) HTML Tags

Tags: c#, regex, replace, html-agility-pack

I'm looking way to clear/remove all HTML tags they have nothing...

For example:

```
<p></p><div> to make links</div><b> </b>
<a href="http://foo.com"></a><p> for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
</p><strong></strong><i></i>
```

To:

```
<div> to make links</div><p> for linebreak add 2 spaces at end</p>
```

*//I'm sure it is not dublicate.*

Comment: So, you *aren't* actually looking for a regex to do this, right? Because we know how that will go: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1783619

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I feel removing empty elements is actually a valid use of regular expressions.

Comment: @Dai Feel free to answer. When I try to use regexs to solve a problem, I generally end up with two problems :)

Comment: personally I think it's a bad idea: <script src="/path/to/script.js"></script> would be clobbered if you're removing empty tags.

Comment: CSS/Javascript may use empty tags in ways Regex will not be able to understand. This is not going to work for everything.

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu You tagged this `HtmlAgilityPack` so why not doing it in HAP way : `var emptyNodes = myDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[not(normalize-space())]");`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string RemoveUnusedTags(this string source)
{
    return Regex.Replace(source, @"<(\w+)\b(?:\s+[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:""[^""]*""|'[^']*'|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*/?>\s*</\1\s*>", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex like this:

```
<(\w+)\s*.*?>\s*?</\1>
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/oD8iN8/2)**

[image]

The idea is to look for tags (with or without attributes) that contains empty values. For the sample input you added, the output is:

```
<div> to make links</div>
<p> for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this QA as a starting point ( [Regular expression to match empty HTML tags that may contain embedded JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705750/regular-expression-to-match-empty-html-tags-that-may-contain-embedded-jstl) ), we have the regex `<(\w+)(?:\s+\w+="[^"]+(?:"\$[^"]+"[^"]+)?")*>\s*</\1>`.

Then it's just a matter of feeding this into .NET's Regex engine:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"<(\w+)(?:\s+\w+=""[^""]+(?:""\$[^""]+"[^""]+)?"")*>\s*</\1>");
String output = r.Replace( inputString, String.Empty );
```

This regular expression will match any text of the form `<foo bar="baz"> </foo>` where attributes are entirely optional, and there may only be whitespace between the opening and closing tags.

Comment: Just to be clear, the author of that answer noted that there is likely HTML that exists that is empty but would not match this regex.